# .delay() not working when changing background-color of <div>

Tags: jquery, css

I am just learning JQUERY and I have been playing around with delay() I wrote a fiddle to show you... What I am trying to do is when a button is clicked, change the background-color of the div and then after a few moments switch the background color again. But when I try it, it just switches to the second color and skips the first.

HTML:

```
<div class = "animation">


</div> 

<button id = "change"> Click </button>
```

Here is the Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#change").click(function(){

    $(".animation").css("background", "blue").delay(700).css("background", "red");


    });
});
```

Here is the link:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPzYb/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only works for items in the queue (such as animations).

For anything else, use [a regular old timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
$("#change").click(function() {
    var $el = $(".animation");

    $el.css("background", "blue");

    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.css("background", "red");
    }, 700);
});
```

Comment: @cipherous Also check out `setInterval()`, doesn't make sense to use it in this instance, but it's also helpful for animations / looping

Comment: We can use delay here. Please check my answer.

Comment: @JustinJohn - Of course we can. As I stated in my answer, anything on the queue can use `delay`. The question is: should we? Why not just use the native `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use delay with queue here

```
  $(".animation").css("background","blue").delay(700)
         .queue(function() {
            $(this).css("background", "red").dequeue();
   });
```

Wrap above snippet  inside click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="lock"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lock').prepend('<tr><td>hello</td><td>cool</td><td>dad</td></tr>');
        $("#lock tr").css('background-color','yellow');
    $("#lock tr")
    .delay(4000)
    .queue(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","red").dequeue();
    })
    .fadeIn();

});

</script>
```

Try this.