# javascript delay is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my table row my requirement is first time displaying background color of row in yellow color after 4 seconds the color become fade
i am using following code

```js
$('#lock').prepend('<tr><td>hello</td><td>cool</td><td>dad</td></tr>');
```

I am using following code

```
$("#lock tr").css('background-color','yellow').delay(4000).css('background-color','fade');
```

problem delay is not working

Comment: Had you add `jquery.min.js`?

Comment: yes poonam i used jquary. min.js

Comment: Try adding  this script  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: do you see any JS error in console?

Comment: Well yes there some flaws in the code. For instance, setting the background-color to 'fade'. It is also recommended to use a combination of JS and CSS.

Comment: there is no error in console @techie

Comment: as @JasonK spotted `.css('background-color','fade')` doesn't seem to be valid.. you should try it with `.css('background-color','#fff')`

Comment: But the first color can't take,it immediately take '#fff'

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css

Comment: @MidhunSuresh Why don't you try out my answer and fix the problem?

Comment: I tried it,but it doesn't works in my code

Comment: @JasonK is correct his solution is better for this..which browser are you using & you should be sure that CSS rules are applied correctly as he states... `.css()` method wont work like you expect as stated in the answer of the link I gave.

Comment: @MidhunSuresh Try the last piece of code I've added

Answer (score 5):

Let CSS render the background-color transition (quicker then JS):

```
#lock {
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}    
#lock.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now once the DOM is loaded, add the following JavaScript right before closing the `<body>` tag:

```
// JS solution
setTimeout(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('lock');
    element.classList.add('red');
}, 4000);

// jQuery solution
$('#lock').delay(4000).addClass('red'); // no good, check the edit.
```

**Edit**

If you want to know why your code doesn't work, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421985/delay-not-working-when-changing-background-color-of-div) answer. The `delay` function only seems to work on items in the queue (such as animations). For anything else, use a regular old timer as given in my first JS solution:

```
var $table = $("#lock");
$table.css("background-color", "yellow");

setTimeout(function () {
    $table.css("background-color", "red");
}, 4000);
```

If you also want a fade transition, you'd still have to use some CSS.

Good luck.